# error Capybara: Reason: expected to find css "fat_anual" but there were no matches

Tags: automated-tests, capybara

Telefone celular:*Campo de preenchimento obrigatório

my code with siteprism

class CriaScreenCadastro < SitePrism::Page
set_url 'https://quasar-flash-staging.herokuapp.com/#boxCadastro'

element  :fone_cel,      'div#boxCadastro input[name="telefone_celular"]'

end

expect(screen_cadastro).to have_field 'fone_cel',  disabled: false

error:  Reason:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcflT.png)expected to find css "fat_anual" but there were no matches
----------------------------------------------

my site: https://quasar-flash-staging.herokuapp.com/#boxCadastro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not clear from your question where the “fat_anual” CSS is coming from but I believe for your expectation you want

```
expect(screen_cadastro).to have_fone_cel
```

Since you’ve defined the element